# How can I calculate percentage in Spark SQL data frame?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have aadhaar card dataset. I need to find the top 3 states where the percentage of Aadhaar cards being generated for males is the highest. The dataset contains the data:

```
Date,Registrar,Private_Agency,State,District,Sub_District,PinCode,Gender,Age,AadharGenerated,EnrolmentRejected,MobileNumProvided
20150420,Civil Supplies - A&N Islands,India Computer Technology,Andaman and Nicobar Islands,South Andaman,Ferrargunj,744105,F,91,1,0,0
20150420,Civil Supplies - A&N Islands,India Computer Technology,Andaman and Nicobar Islands,South Andaman,Port Blair,744101,F,4,1,0,0
20150420,Civil Supplies - A&N Islands,India Computer Technology,Andaman and Nicobar Islands,South Andaman,Port Blair,744101,F,5,1,0,0
20150420,Civil Supplies - A&N Islands,India Computer Technology,Andaman and Nicobar Islands,South Andaman,Port Blair,744101,F,8,1,0,0
20150420,Civil Supplies - A&N Islands,India Computer Technology,Andaman and Nicobar Islands,South Andaman,Port Blair,744101,F,11,1,0,0
20150420,Civil Supplies - A&N Islands,India Computer Technology,Andaman and Nicobar Islands,South Andaman,Port Blair,744101,F,12,1,0,0
20150420,Civil Supplies - A&N Islands,India Computer Technology,Andaman and Nicobar Islands,South Andaman,Port Blair,744101,F,17,1,0,0
20150420,Civil Supplies - A&N Islands,India Computer Technology,Andaman and Nicobar Islands,South Andaman,Port Blair,744101,F,28,2,0,0
20150420,Civil Supplies - A&N Islands,India Computer Technology,Andaman and Nicobar Islands,South Andaman,Port Blair,744101,F,30,1,0,0
20150420,Civil Supplies - A&N Islands,India Computer Technology,Andaman and Nicobar Islands,South Andaman,Port Blair,744101,F,31,1,0,0
20150420,Civil Supplies - A&N Islands,India Computer Technology,Andaman and Nicobar Islands,South Andaman,Port Blair,744101,F,34,2,0,0
20150420,Civil Supplies - A&N Islands,India Computer Technology,Andaman and Nicobar Islands,South Andaman,Port Blair,744101,F,39,1,0,0
20150420,Civil Supplies - A&N Islands,India Computer Technology,Andaman and Nicobar Islands,South Andaman,Port Blair,744101,F,44,1,0,0
20150420,Civil Supplies - A&N Islands,India Computer Technology,Andaman and Nicobar Islands,South Andaman,Port Blair,744101,M,29,1,0,0
20150420,Civil Supplies - A&N Islands,India Computer Technology,Andaman and Nicobar Islands,South Andaman,Port Blair,744101,M,38,1,0,0
20150420,Civil Supplies - A&N Islands,India Computer Technology,Andaman and Nicobar Islands,South Andaman,Port Blair,744101,M,45,1,0,0
20150420,Civil Supplies - A&N Islands,India Computer Technology,Andaman and Nicobar Islands,South Andaman,Port Blair,744101,M,64,1,0,0
20150420,Civil Supplies - A&N Islands,India Computer Technology,Andaman and Nicobar Islands,South Andaman,Port Blair,744101,M,66,1,0,0
20150420,Civil Supplies - A&N Islands,India Computer Technology,Andaman and Nicobar Islands,South Andaman,Port Blair,744101,M,75,1,0,0
20150420,Civil Supplies - A&N Islands,India Computer Technology,Andaman and Nicobar Islands,South Andaman,Port Blair,744103,F,9,1,0,0
20150420,Civil Supplies - A&N Islands,India Computer Technology,Andaman and Nicobar Islands,South Andaman,Port Blair,744103,F,44,1,0,0
20150420,Civil Supplies - A&N Islands,India Computer Technology,Andaman and Nicobar Islands,South Andaman,Port Blair,744103,F,54,1,0,0
20150420,Civil Supplies - A&N Islands,India Computer Technology,Andaman and Nicobar Islands,South Andaman,Port Blair,744103,F,59,1,0,0
20150420,Civil Supplies - A&N Islands,India Computer Technology,Andaman and Nicobar Islands,South Andaman,Port Blair,744103,M,27,1,0,0
20150420,Civil Supplies - A&N Islands,India Computer Technology,Andaman and Nicobar Islands,South Andaman,Port Blair,744103,M,29,1,0,0
20150420,Bank Of India,Frontech Systems Pvt Ltd,Andhra Pradesh,Krishna,Kanchikacherla,521185,M,40,1,0,0
20150420,CSC e-Governance Services India Limited,BASIX,Andhra Pradesh,Srikakulam,Veeraghattam,532460,F,24,1,0,0
```

I tried but getting error:

```
sqlC.sql("SELECT STATE,
          (MALEADHAR/ADHAARDATA*100) AS PERCENTMALE 
         FROM 
                (SELECT STATE,SUM(ADHAARDATA) AS MALEADHAR 
                 FROM 
                       (SELECT State, SUM(AadharGenerated) AS ADHAARDATA
                         FROM data Group By State)
                         where Gender==='M') AS MALEADHAR 
                          GROUP BY STATE") 
                 SELECT STATE, SUM(AadharGenerated) AS MALEADAHAR FROM data where Gender='M' GROUP BY STATE")
```

How can I correct the query.

Comment: Format your code.

Comment: You are using spark sql but state dataframe. you get a dataframe back - a little confusing.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuing on, I remember the better approach!!!

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val df = sc.parallelize(Seq(
   ("A", "X", 2, 100), ("A", "X", 7, 100), ("B", "X", 10, 100),
   ("C", "X", 1, 100), ("D", "X", 50, 100), ("E", "X", 30, 100)
    )).toDF("c1", "c2", "Val1", "Val2")

val df2 = df
  .groupBy("c1")
  .agg(sum("Val1").alias("sum"))
  .withColumn("fraction", col("sum") /  sum("sum").over())

df2.show
```

Comment: Could anyone please tell me what is the use of over() in the line .withColumn("fraction", col("sum") /  sum("sum").over()) ?

Comment: @RittikDe  Try without and you will see.

Answer (score 1):

Apply after looking at this related simple approach. Other ways too, but an easy approach and you can adapt accordingly to one or one groupings, with filtering, etc. Some research required.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val df = sc.parallelize(Seq(
   ("A", "X", 2, 100), ("A", "X", 7, 100), ("B", "X", 10, 100),
   ("C", "X", 1, 100), ("D", "X", 50, 100), ("E", "X", 30, 100)
    )).toDF("c1", "c2", "Val1", "Val2")

val total = df.select(col("Val1")).rdd.map(_(0).asInstanceOf[Int]).reduce(_+_)
// Or val total2: Long = df.agg(sum("Val1").cast("long")).first.getLong(0)

val df2 = df.groupBy($"c1").sum("Val1")
val df3 = df2.withColumn("perc_total", ($"sum(val1)" / total))

df3.show
```

Gives:

```
+---+---------+----------+
| c1|sum(Val1)|perc_total|
+---+---------+----------+
|  E|       30|       0.3|
|  B|       10|       0.1|
|  D|       50|       0.5|
|  C|        1|      0.01|
|  A|        9|      0.09|
+---+---------+----------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using SQL queries you can simply use spark's built in functions. In order to use the functions you need to first create the data frame from the data:

```
 import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
 import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{StructType, StructField, StringType,IntegerType}; 

#Schema
val schema = new StructType(
Array(
   StructField("date",IntegerType,true),
  StructField("registrar",StringType,true),
  StructField("private_agency",StringType,true),
  StructField("state",StringType,true),
  StructField("district",StringType,true),
  StructField("sub_district",StringType,true),
  StructField("pincode",IntegerType,true),
  StructField("gender",StringType,true),
  StructField("age",IntegerType,true),
  StructField("aadhar_generated",IntegerType,true),
  StructField("rejected",IntegerType,true),
  StructField("mobile_number",IntegerType,true),
  StructField("email_id",IntegerType,true)
  )
)


#Loading data

    val data = spark.read.option("header", "false").schema(schema).csv("aadhaar_data.csv")





#query 

data.groupBy("state", "gender").agg(sum("aadhar_generated")).filter(col("gender") === "M").orderBy(desc("sum(aadhar_generated)"))  

data.show
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, with SQL, just add the extra filtering etc. This is where the buck stops.

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView("SOQTV")

spark.sql(" SELECT c1, SUM(Val1) / (SELECT SUM(Val1) FROM SOQTV) as Perc_Total_for_SO_Question  " +
      " FROM SOQTV " + 
      " GROUP BY c1 ").show()
```

Same answers gotten.

Comment: Thanks for answering. But there still have one major bottleneck. The scenario asks to calculate percentage of males for which aadhaar card is generated. How will I go on considering that if I create a dataframe which contains on Male. Hw will I join it with total and create percentage. I am stuck in this problem since days. Please help me.

Comment: But can't you extrapolate from the examples given? You should be nearly there.

Comment: Great, the other examples are also useful. More than one way to skin a cat and note that many steps get combined into a Stage. So clarity can be gotten in defining a solution in many cases.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler approach - i.e. not just using Nested SQL which is also possible of course, but a more step-wise approach that uses both SQL and DFs.

Note that absence of a given combination (in this case c1) means 0%, that can be solved otherwise.

You can now adapt in same way, I have provided similar variable names. You can order, drop, rename columns.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val df = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  ("A", "X", 2, 100, "M", "Y"), ("F", "X", 7, 100, "M", "Y"), ("B", "X", 10, 100, "F", "Y"),
  ("C", "X", 1, 100, "F", "N"), ("D", "X", 50, 100, "M", "N"), ("E", "X", 30, 100, "M", "Y"),
  ("D", "X", 1, 100, "F", "N"), ("A", "X", 50, 100, "M", "N"), ("A", "X", 30, 100, "M", "Y"),
  ("D", "X", 1, 100, "M", "N"), ("X", "X", 50, 100, "M", "Y"), ("A", "X", 30, 100, "F", "Y"),
  ("K", "X", 1, 100, "M", "N"), ("K", "X", 50, 100, "M", "Y")
)).toDF("c1", "c2", "Val1", "Val2", "male_Female_Flag", "has_This")

df.createOrReplaceTempView("SOQTV")

spark.sql(
   "select * " +
   "from SOQTV " +
   "where 1 = 1 order by 1,5,6 ").show()

val dfA = spark.sql(" SELECT c1, count(*) " +
      " FROM SOQTV " + 
      " WHERE male_Female_Flag = 'M' " +
      " GROUP BY c1 ")

 val dfB = spark.sql(" SELECT c1, count(*) " +
      " FROM SOQTV " + 
      " WHERE male_Female_Flag = 'M' AND has_This = 'Y' " +
      " GROUP BY c1 ")

 val dfC = dfB.join(dfA, dfA("c1") === dfB("c1"), "inner")
 val colNames = Seq("c1", "Male_Has_Something", "c1_Again", "Male")
 val dfD = dfC.toDF(colNames: _*)

 dfC.show
 dfD.show
 dfD.withColumn("Percentage", (col("Male_Has_Something") / col("Male")) * 100 ).show
```

This gives:

```
 +---+------------------+--------+----+-----------------+
 | c1|Male_Has_Something|c1_Again|Male|       Percentage|
 +---+------------------+--------+----+-----------------+
 |  K|                 1|       K|   2|             50.0|
 |  F|                 1|       F|   1|            100.0|
 |  E|                 1|       E|   1|            100.0|
 |  A|                 2|       A|   3|66.66666666666666|
 |  X|                 1|       X|   1|            100.0|
 +---+------------------+--------+----+-----------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Another version of accepted answer using window functions

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val df = sc.parallelize(Seq(
   ("A", "X", 2, 100), ("A", "X", 7, 100), ("B", "X", 10, 100),
   ("C", "X", 1, 100), ("D", "X", 50, 100), ("E", "X", 30, 100)
    )).toDF("c1", "c2", "Val1", "Val2")
df.show
println("using group by agg")
val df2 = df
  .groupBy("c1")
  .agg(sum("Val1").alias("sum"))
  .withColumn("fraction", col("sum") /  sum("sum").over())
df2.show
println("using window function sum")
 df.createOrReplaceTempView("test")
 spark.sql("select  distinct c1, concat( sum(Val1) over(Partition by c1)/(sum(Val1) over()) * 100 , '%') as percent from test ").show
```

Result :

```
+---+---+----+----+
| c1| c2|Val1|Val2|
+---+---+----+----+
|  A|  X|   2| 100|
|  A|  X|   7| 100|
|  B|  X|  10| 100|
|  C|  X|   1| 100|
|  D|  X|  50| 100|
|  E|  X|  30| 100|
+---+---+----+----+

using group by agg
+---+---+--------+
| c1|sum|fraction|
+---+---+--------+
|  A|  9|    0.09|
|  B| 10|     0.1|
|  C|  1|    0.01|
|  D| 50|     0.5|
|  E| 30|     0.3|
+---+---+--------+

using window function sum
+---+-------+
| c1|percent|
+---+-------+
|  A|   9.0%|
|  B|  10.0%|
|  C|   1.0%|
|  D|  50.0%|
|  E|  30.0%|
+---+-------+
```